# How can I implement dynamic user-specific customization options in a Python Streamlit app

Tags: python, web-applications, streamlit

"I'm developing a Python application using Streamlit, and I want to provide my users with the ability to customize the app's appearance and functionality based on their preferences. Specifically, I'd like to implement dynamic user-specific customization options that persist between sessions.

Are there any recommended approaches or best practices for implementing this kind of customization feature in a Streamlit app? I'm particularly interested in allowing users to select different color themes, adjust layout configurations, and personalize certain functionalities.

I've explored the Streamlit documentation and found ways to customize the app globally,

Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this dynamic customization feature within a Streamlit app would be greatly appreciated. If there are any relevant code examples, tutorials, or third-party libraries, please share them